# How to embed fonts in a pdf or pptx document?

Tags: pdf, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint document (I am using Powerpoint 2016 for Mac), and I am trying to embed fonts. If I embed the fonts in the powerpoint presentation, I want to export the pptx file to a pdf which should have embedded fonts too. An alternative is to directly edit the pdf to embed the fonts. So far I tried to print the document using preview, because as far as I know it automatically embeds fonts. But it forces me to use the A4 format, or other formats that are not fit for a pdf presentation. What if want to keep the current format and just embed fonts?

[image]

Comment: printing them wont embed font though.. need to [save it as a pdf](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-powerpoint-presentations-as-pdf-files-9b5c786b-9c6e-4fe6-81f6-9372f77c47c8) properly.

Comment: I chose “download as pdf” in powerpoint online. Are the fonts embedded in this case?

Comment: hmm, not sure, i thought you used the offline one. if yes, that should be embedded if you specify on the save option. download as pdf? is this one ms office online? if yes better check on [WebApps STE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What build version are you running? It is my understanding the Font Embedding in Mac PowerPoint was just recently released to the Insider builds. 16.16.180718